# how to convert an image to sRGB icc color profile using imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I have an .heic image (with come from an iOS device). How to convert it to sRGB ?
Before I was doing like this :

To convert to sRGB:

```
MagickProfileImage(Wand, 'icc', <sRGB2014.icc>);
```

but it's seam to not work :( 
After doing this the colors are completely wrong ...

example of an image with ICC profile :
[image]

And what I have after I replaced the profile by a sRGB profile 
[image]

original image (heic) here:  https://filebin.ca/4fy7yPEUfwga/picture.zip

Comment: It is not a good idea to remove profiles, since there are many sRGB profiles. Also if you input does not have a profile, then you will need one for the input and one for the output.

Comment: @fmw42, yes even if i don't remove the sRGB profile i just add nothing change :( see exemple i just add in the question

Comment: @fmw42 I updated the question, basically I only want to convert the image to sRGB profile

Comment: What is your Imagemagick version, date of the version and platform?  `convert -version` for IM6 or `magick -version` for IM 7.

Comment: What are you doing to process the file besides removing the profile. The following works fine for me by converting from your Apple Display P3 icc profile to sRGB.icc. `convert img.jpg -profile sRGB.icc img6.jpg` in IM 6.9.10.43 and `magick img.jpg -profile sRGB.icc img7.jpg` in IM 7.0.8.43. Both are visually the same as your input. Again, I would not remove the profile once you install one. Otherwise, different display/viewers will apply their own profile and the result will not look consistent from viewer to viewer.

Comment: P.S. I am not sure why your image is showing an Apple P3 icc profile, which I see from identify -verbose a04tx.jpg. Perhaps this forum has added it when you uploaded. You might zip your file, upload somewhere and then put the URL here so we are sure to have your actual input image. The image provided above is jpg. But I thought you said you had an heic image? What do you get when you do `identify -verbose` on your heic image?

Comment: @fmw42 I was on imagemagick 7.0.7.23 under windows. But after reading your comment I try under 7.0.8.43 then yes both are visually the same BUT if you try to check the icc of the resulting img7.jpg you will see that their is now NO ICC (you can check here: http://metapicz.com/#landing). in 7.0.7.23 imagemagick found an icc profile (the one i remove) and in imagemagick 7.0.8.43 then it's found no icc !

Comment: @fmw42 I uploaded the original .heic image (it's the iOS format) here: https://filebin.ca/4fy7yPEUfwga/picture.zip

Comment: @fmw42 I think it's a bug I submit a post here: https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=35968&p=165704#p165704